# how to get an multidimensional menu out of my database?

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I want to need to make a menu where i don't know how deep the menu will be.

this is how my database table looks like:
table `menu` fields `id`, `parent_id`, `name`

i already tryed this to get a nice array back, but it dont work:

```
public function get()
{
    $nodeList = array();
    $tree     = array();
    $query = $this->db->get('menu');
    $result = $query->result_array();
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $nodeList[$row['id']] = array_merge($row, array('children' => array()));
    }

    foreach ($nodeList as $nodeId => &$node) {
        if (!$node['parent'] || !array_key_exists($node['parent'], $nodeList)) {
            $tree[] =& $node;
        } else {
            $nodeList[$node['parent']]['children'][] =& $node;
        }
    }

    return $nodeList;
}
```

eventually I want to achieve this(a nice looking menu):

```
<ul>
<li><a href="">Apple<a/>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Iphone</a></li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">4S</a></li>
                <li><a href="">5</a></li>
            </ul>
        <li><a href="">Ipad</a></li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="">5</a></li>
            </ul>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="">Samsung<a/>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Galaxy</a></li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">S3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">S4</a></li>
            </ul>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I hope you understand my question and can help me. i REALLYY!! need this.

thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `get()` should probably return `$tree`, not `$nodeList`. Other than that, it seems perfectly fine.

Update. This example shows how to build HTML for nested menu:

```php
function getUl($nodes)
{
    $result = "<ul>\n";
    foreach ($nodes as $n) {
        $result .= '<li><a href="...">...</a>';
        if (!empty($n['children'])) {
            $result .= getUl($n['children']);
        }
        $result .= "</li>\n";
    }
    $result .= "\n</ul>";
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: omg that was stupid of me, thx:D but can you also help with te setting up the menu? i have no idea how to fix that

Comment: @apero try an example I posted.